# Azure Cosmos DB API API for MongoDB: Shared throughput limit

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Is there any limit for number of collections which can have shared throughput in Server Version 3.6 or 4.0?

More details:

I use the Server version 3.6 with 120 collections in total, out of which 20 collections have shared throughput.

I am planning to upgrade to 4.0 and would like to have 60 collections with shared throughput.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#provisioned-throughput-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput), the limit is 25 containers per database that can utilize the shared throughput defined on the database. Beyond 25, you will need to create containers with dedicated throughput.

This is what the documentation says:

> Containers in a shared throughput database share the throughput (RU/s)
> allocated to that database. **With standard (manual) provisioned
> throughput, you can have up to 25 containers with a minimum of 400
> RU/s on the database**. With autoscale provisioned throughput, you can
> have up to 25 containers in a database with autoscale max 4000 RU/s
> (scales between 400 - 4000 RU/s).

Comment: Documentation says - "An Azure Cosmos container is the unit of scalability both for provisioned throughput and storage. In other words, the provisioned throughput on the database is shared among all the “shared throughput” containers" - But not able to understand in terms of collections how the container works. Basically I would like to know how containers are connected with collections? I've set 14000 as RU for autoscale provisioned throughput of my database. What is the limitation now I have in terms of collections? Should I split the DB to achieve better performance as mentioned in my Q?

Comment: `container` **is** `collection`. 14000 RUs will be shared by 25 containers (collections) in your database.